# Windows 10 stuck in reboot loop

Tags: reboot, runtime-error

I have a vaio laptop, series SVF1532, Windows 10, I beleive that I have the updated till the date, today when going out, I tried to turn the laptop off using the windows start option, but it did not turn off, so I force turned it off by the laptop button, when I came back home and tried to turn it on again, the windows booted up till the lock screen, but before typing the password in, I got a blue scrren indicating hard drive problem ( I don't mean the blue screen of death), then it restarted and then from that moment I've had the reboot loop problem. I tried to search the net, the F8 button was suggested, which for me it doesn't work, cause when the vaio brand comes up, then in spite of a second some windows appear to open and close, then again I have the vaio mark, under which is written: preparing for automatic reboot, then changes to another phrase " diagnosing drive problem", then to " attempting to restore ", and after a long time it restarts and again and again.

I have also the assist button, that gives me the BIOS configuration management option and also restore ones, the boot mode options I am given is Legacy UEFI

That the legacy one just comes up with " operating system not found "

P.S.
Now I have the boot up CD, that boots up a safe mode,  I guess,  but still it seems that I should do something to repair my boot up,because I can only boot up with this CD into the safe mode

I checked it here 
[pcerror fix](http://www.pcerror-fix.com/simple-methods-to-fix-endless-reboot-loop-after-windows-10-update)

But yet I don't understand how to scan registry files via profile list

P.S.2: booting using the CD,  I tried to remove the last updates as I was advised,  but to my wonder,  navigating from control panel to the visualize installed updates window, I noticed that no updates are shown!!  since I use windows 10 home version, I have no choice to defer the updates, [updates win 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-windows-update-in-windows-10)
So this seems strange to me I also put the image of what I see in the window, unfortunately it's in Italian, but I think it's clear where I am 
[image: control panel visualize updates]

Comment: Have you tried booting into safe mode and uninstalling the latest update you got from windows update? I've had this happen before a couple times in the past with various win updates.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove No, neither F8 nor any of the F buttons worked for me,  I read here: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-an-endless-Windows-10-boot-loop-without-a-USB-CD-recovery/answer/Jeff-Gerckens?srid=TlVr&share=7b180ec2 that in window 8 and higher the F8 button hardly can work, but in my case I think there's a problem with even being able to use it, because right after the VAIO name screen appears in the beginning of the boot,  when it starts to bring up the next screen,  I see some windows open and close very fast

Comment: ...I don't know what they are, and then it goes to the next screen that says diagnosing system problems, that stays for a long time and is followed by the next phrase: attemting system restore that then leads to restart again, but I mentioned that now using a CD that helps to boot up on safe mode, ok I don't know how and which updates to uninstal

Comment: look for the ones with the most recent install date. Uninstall those.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove thank you for your answer,  but I checked and did not find any update installed, please check my question, I added some more details